# How do I create two apps with same firebase database in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

For my project I have to create 2 apps where 1 is for the customer(i.e. he can see all products) & the second is for the seller(i.e. he can see which customer has bought his products). I have already created a new firebase project. But how do I connect both the customer & seller app to the same firebase project in Flutter so that when the seller lists an item a customer can see it?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy to do so with firebase.

1. Go to Firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com and open your project
2. Click on the `Add App` button, (as you normally would to add the first app).
3. Choose your platform android or ios.
   [image: Firebase Project]
4. Then follow the procedures on the screen, add your package name, SHA-keys (if you require oauth)
5. Download and save the firebase config file.

You can generate different config files for different apps in the same firebase project, and use them with different code sources.